# Reset ActivatedRoute in Angular 4

Tags: angular2-routing, typescript2.0

There is some code I was using that builds up a series of breadcrumb links via a do while loop. The loop terminates when the ActivatedRoute is null as below:

```
 constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
      this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((event) => {
      this.breadcrumbs = [];
      let currentRoute = this.route.root,
      url = '';
      do {
        const childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
        currentRoute = null;
        childrenRoutes.forEach(route => {
          if (route.outlet === 'primary') {
            const routeSnapshot = route.snapshot;
            url += '/' + routeSnapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
            this.breadcrumbs.push({
              label: route.snapshot.data,
              url:   url
            });
            currentRoute = route;
          }
        });
      } while (currentRoute);
    });
```

After updating to Angular 4.4.4 and TypeScript 2.5.3 the following assignment no longer compiles:

```
currentRoute = null;
```

where current route is an ActivatedRoute.

> Type null is not assignable to type ActivateRoute

I've tried

```
private route: ActivatedRoute | any
```

but that in turn breaks other parts of the method. So im not sure if i should be fixing those issues or resetting ActivatedRoute in a more appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `ActivatedRoute | null`, but I generally shy away from `null` unless I have a compelling reason for a value of `null`.

Try using `currentRoute = undefined`.